# Question regarding complex conjugates.

Tags: complex-numbers

$$ \overline{4z+4+4i} = z+13−14i$$

The conjugate becomes $4z+4-4i$, but whenever I then try to solve for $z$, I end up getting the wrong answer when checking the answer.

Comment: If $\overline{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$, your hypothesis is $$\overline{4z+4+4i} = z + 13 - 14i$$ right?  The left hand side is $4 \overline{z} + 4 - 4i$, not $4z+4-4i$.

Comment: @D_S Consider converting your comment into an answer so that this question might be removed form the unanswered tab.

Comment: @D_S Oh I see, but how would I then solve for z?

Comment: You could write $z$ as $a+bi$ and solve for the real numbers $a$ and $b$

Comment: @D_S Alright I got the answer, thank you my friend :)